# Angular Firebase not fetching realtime results, console.log says undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I am unable to fetch realtime data from cloud firestore. If I do console.log instead of returning in the service and simply call the function(not subscribe to it) it works.

This is the code in my chatService file

```
    getRealTimeChats(): any {
    this.db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const chat: ChatModel[] = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data() as ChatModel;
        chat.push(data);
      });
      return chat;
    });
}
```

Below is the code in my chat.ts file

```
this.chatService.getRealTimeChats().subscribe((chats: ChatModel[]) => {
      this.chats = chats;
});
```

Comment: Your getRealTimeChats function doesn't actually return an observable. It's actually not returning anything at all.  The return statement inside the onSnapshot callback is not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onSnapshot method recives a callback when the data is loaded. You can't return a value because nobody will recive it. Also, your getRealTimeChats isn't an observable, so, you can't subscribe to it.
Maybe you can return a custom Observable. Something like this

```
getRealTimeChats(): any {
    const subject = new Subject();
    const observable = subject.asObservable();

    this.db.collection('chats').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const chat: ChatModel[] = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = doc.data() as ChatModel;
            chat.push(data);
        });
        subject.next(chat);
    });

    return observable;   
}
```

and when you call it:

```
this.chatService.getRealTimeChats().subscribe((chats: ChatModel[]) => {
      this.chats = chats;
});
```

Comment: While this works and displays data on the HTML, I still have to refresh the page to see any additions I make to the Database which is not the intended behaviour. It is not "realtime"

Comment: Nice! remember to set the subscription to unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy